# On-campus interview: Faculty exit interview

Tags: faculty-application, tenure-track

I am going to do an on-campus interview and one of the items (the last one on my last day) is "Exit interview" for one hour with 4 faculty members (search committee chair, co-chair, ...). I was wondering what this interview is?

Comment: Country? Your country?

Comment: The country is the US

Comment: Could you post the answer?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist: It was an interview with all committee members, asking extra questions, my interview experience and also a time for me to ask my questions if I have any. For example, they asked how do you think about our department after your visit, ...

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a panel.  Probably pretty important.  If you looked good during the day, they will want to confirm.  If questionable, gives them a chance to probe specifics.  If meeting is cancelled or senior members don't show, you can guess it's a ding.

Comment: This can also be an interview where the candidate is expected to ask any questions they have and the committee members or department chair explain what will happen next in the search process.  If you've already had scheduled interviews with the whole search committee or individually with each search committee member, then this is probably meant to be your chance to ask questions of the committee.

Comment: Agreed.  Standard stuff on a closeout.

Comment: Based on the agenda, I already should have met three of the members before and only one of them is new. I think they will ask me some extra questions because they are using "Exit INTERVIEW", not "Exit MEETING". Is this interview will be something like a Skype interview with questions about teaching, research, future plans, ...?